# How to get element value of selected row in a subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Sub Form in MS Access as below :

[image: Screen Shot]

Is there any way to get the string value of the selected row when the user click on the row ?

I have tried using the ReportKey as follow  :

```
SELECT MyRowName From TAB_MySubFormName WHERE TAB_MySubFormName.ReportKey=" & ReportKey
```

but the result of the ReportKey is always 1 which I guess it's the first element even thought I have clicked on the last  element in the table

Comment: String value or relative row number? If you just want the string, 'Debug.Print Me.txtSomeField' will work.  For row number, see:https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=249063  (Assuming you use the OnCurrent event in the subform)

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn is it mandatory to use the OnCurrent event?

Comment: No, it's not mandatory. You could use any event that has scope of the control you want to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up finding my error

I had to precise the `SUB_Form.Form.ReportKey`  no need to precise the sub form name just simply add `SUB_Form.Form.ReportKey` , which  means I had to do this :

```
SELECT MyRowName From TAB_MySubFormName WHERE TAB_MySubFormName.ReportKey=" & SUB_Form.Form.ReportKey
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your main form:

```
MsgBox Nz(Me.YourSubform.Form!SomeField)
```